# Cannot resolve method updateAppWidget

Tags: android

I'm new to android Studio and I want to display the time and update it so that it shows the current time. I managed to display the current time when i open the app but now i want it to count up the seconds as well.

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.appwidget.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView dateTimeDisplay;   //widget, in dem Datum angezeigt wird
    private Calendar calendar;
    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat;
    private String date;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dateTimeDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_date_display);
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

        updateTime();
        futureWidgetUpdate();
    }

    private void updateTime() {
        String data = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
        dateTimeDisplay.setText(data);
    }

    private void futureWidgetUpdate() {
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, TextView.class);
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
        int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(componentName);
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            TextView.updateAppWidget(this, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }
    }
}
```

Which class do I have to us instead of TextView?